# How to have yearly versions of same site with different content (like yearly conferences)?

Tags: multisite, development-strategy

Past year I build a site for a yearly conference event. http://reunionterapeutica.gtpbarcelona.com/

The 2015 event has done yet. Now the client wants to archive the 2015 event content in a folder or subdomain that can be visited by users, and use the root domain for the information of next year conference, and every year the client wants to do the same.

I have not considered this use when I build the site past year. So maybe I would had to consider other development strategies from the beginning.

So, which strategy would you use for this case of sites? When the same theme and structure will be used every year, but part of the content will change (dates, program, speakers, venue, organizers....), and also using WPML plugin because the site is multilanguage.

It's multisite the best method?  There is another approach that could be also useful?

Thanks!

Comment: A multisite with `conference-YYYY.example.tld` subdomains or `example.tld/conference-YYYY` subdirectories sounds like a neat fit to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks @birgire Any other suggestion?

Comment: You might also take a look at `wordcamp.org` and how it's constructed, e.g. `sf.wordcamp.org/2013/`, `sf.wordcamp.org/2014/` and  `london.wordcamp.org/2015`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this is what I want to achieve, but it seems that they have an entire wp's install in each year folder: 'https://sf.wordcamp.org/2013/wp-content/plugins/' and ''https://sf.wordcamp.org/2014/wp-content/plugins/'